# MATLAB Figure Title gets cut off

Tags: image, matlab

When I use the following code to display an image, it displays fine, but the figure window is cropped close around the figure so that the title is cut off. It's definitely there though because if I manually make the window taller, then the title becomes visible.

I think this is my fault because a while back I was messing around with default settings for how MATLAB fits the window to the axis. Now I just can't remember the settings that changed this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Code:

```
figure();
imshow(my_img);
title('A Sample Image');
```

Comment: well, I think it is a superuser question, because it is only about GUI of a software, not about the main themes from a stackoverflow question (a specific programming problem / a software algorithm / software tools commonly used by programmers / matters that are unique to the programming profession).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I found it. In R2010a, it can be fixed by going "File -> Preferences -> Image Processing" and under IMSHOW Display, setting Border Style to Loose. Don't know why I didn't notice this before. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Was your problem exactly as described by me, including Matlab version? If not, I'd recommend starting a new question, referring back to this thread and drawing attention to any differences in your situation so it doesn't get closed immediately as a duplicate question.

Comment: Same exact problem. I fixed by adding an ellipses (...) to the end of my title. The dots get cut off, but the words remain :)

Comment: Solution for me: for 3D plots, make sure NOT to use this: "axis vis3d" !!

Answer (score 0):

Try that: in Figure window, search for options/preferences in menu and then try to recover original options

Later, I'll improve my answer (I don't have Matlab here...).

Comment: OK, I found it. In R2010a, it can be fixed by going "File -> Preferences -> Image Processing" and under IMSHOW Display, setting Border Style to Loose. Don't know why I didn't notice this before. Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk: Add your comment as an answer here and accept it. That way others who have this problem can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Matlab (2008) help (search for Automatic Axes Resize):

"When you add axis labels and a title, the TightInset changes to accommodate the additional text [...] Using OuterPosition as the ActivePositionProperty: As you resize the figure, MATLAB maintains the area defined by the TightInset + Position so the text is not cut off. "

i.e.
`set(gca, 'ActivePositionProperty', 'OuterPosition');`
fixed it

Comment: This code line and nothing are the same. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Pedro77   savage

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in a work around by adding an ellipses to the end of my titles. 3 or 4 dots at the end of your title and the dots will get cut off, but the words remain! It should be noted that this has never happened to me in the past (and only on my Macbook Pro OSX machine), so it might be an install or compatibility issue.

Comment: How you added an ellipse? I'm tired of cropped plot and title. Stupid Matlab. Code sample please?

Comment: An ellipses is merely 3 dots (...); to add them, type `...`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my case (3D plot). The problem was the command `axis vis3d`. So please, do NOT use this:

```
axis vis3d
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution by Blairg23; adding spaces to the end of the title works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the axis.position to smaller [0,0,0.7,0.7] and be able to see the title

Comment: Can you improve your answer?